# How to capture command excuted by user in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I want collect all commands executed by users and also root in linux Os. How do i collect all commands every day.

Is it possible collect all commands through shell script ?

Could you please help me if anyone know this requirement.

**For example**

If user1 execute "ls -l" , we need to capture and root user execute "df -h", we need to capture. I mean. All users execute command in bash shell, we need to capture all commands.

Thanks

Comment: as a log of commands?, that i belive is yet done by linux, so best find where is saved, not?

Comment: 1. this is not possible directly by means of a "command". 2. you _might_ want to collect the history files written by the users shells and evaluate those, though that probably is incomplete, and 3. this is a question of privacy and probably illegal in most situations, certainly it is highly questionable from an ethical point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Use `history` is very bad practice. Because everybody know that users easily can clean their history. 
For such tasks we use `rootsh`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `history` command that returns the commands executed.

You can read [this](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404624/using-the-history-command)

> All of our services are currently running on Linux. In Linux, there is a very useful command to show you all of the last commands that have been recently used. The command is simply called history, but can also be accessed by looking at your .bash_history in your home folder. By default, the history command will show you the last five hundred commands you have entered.

If you wish to view the history one page at a time, you can use the command below. Now, you can simply use the spacebar to view one page at a time or use the down arrow to view one line at a time:

```
history | less
```

To view just the last ten commands, you can use the following:

```
history | tail
```

To view the last 25 commands, just use the following:

```
history 25
```

And if you want to save the execution of history in a file you can use   [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file)

just redirect the output to a file:

```
history > someFile.txt
```

Or if you want to append data:

```
history >> someFile.txt
```

If you want stderr too use this:

```
history &> someFile.txt
```

or this to append:

```
history &>> someFile.txt
```